# CSS Bootstrap AngularJS - How to reduce table row height?

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to reduce the height of any table row in the below plnkr example with CSS/Bootstrap:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ftea6vd1qaPZaXGusZAN

I've tried many approaches like:

```
line-height
padding
margin
height
```

and checked stackoverflow as well as the official documentation. None is working.

What am I missing to reduce the row height in the table (to display more content on the screen)?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Add this line to your style `.table>tbody>tr>td {
        padding: Xpx;
      }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap has dedicated class for this `table-condensed`:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But if you need to go even more condensed you need to adjust the padding on the table cells. Bootstrap has the (bad) habit of using rules with incredibly high [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so that might be why it didn't work for you before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's class    table-condensed

Or

if you want more customization you can put a div inside the cell with any height you want :

```
<td>
    <div style="height: 20px; overflow:hidden;">
        ...
    </div>
</td>
```